# Custom sections Umbraco

Tags: umbraco7

Not even sure I labeled this correctly, I am in the process of converting a site to Umbraco, and there are sections of the site that needs to be edited using the CMS tools in the back end, basically it is a grid with pictures and description text

Here is a sample of the HTML

```
<div class="hi-icon-effect-1 hi-icon-effect-1a">
       <a class="hi-icon">
           <img class="img-responsive " id="ImgSales" src="../../Images/sales_icon_circle_grey.png" alt="">
       </a>
       <p style="padding-left:5px;" id="lblSales" class="">Sales</p>
 </div>
```

What I would like to be able to do is go to the content section of the admin and edit the list of items and configure the image and text for each item.

http://www2.strikemedia.co.za/

If you view the above link and scroll down there will be a grid of items (services) and it is this list that I want to be able to generate.

I am comfortable with all the technologies used in Umbraco, I just do not know the system well enough to do these kinds of modifications, can someone please assist or point me to the resources that will help me build this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the Archetype package: https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/archetype/

As far as I understand your question you are looking for a way to add X amount of similar items to the contents of a page - for this, Archetype is probably perfect :-)

Once you have your list of items added inside Umbraco, look here: https://github.com/kgiszewski/ArchetypeManual/blob/master/03%20-%20Template%20Usage.md

Use case #1 in this example will allow you to iterate through items and output it with whatever "template" you want (aka the HTML sample you provided).

Comment: Thanks will give it a go and let you know